# LNK1104 cannot open file 'mfc100.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I am trying to rebuild an old program that was made on visual studio 2010, I retargeted the solution to Visual Studio 2022 and did some minor changes, now when I try to rebuild it I get this error

`LNK1104  cannot open file 'mfc100.lib'`

I could not find anything online to fix this problem.
Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: You'll need the MFC library that ships with VS 2010. I believe there is no way to acquire MFC without a full Visual Studio install. Either that or try to retarget MFC to whatever version comes with VS 2022.

Comment: You're still linking against a 2010 version. Check all the settings to make sure they're all updated. The 2022 version should be something like mfc140.lib

Comment: @IInspectable how do I retarget MFC to vs22?

Comment: @ChrisMM how do I do that?

Comment: Right click one the project, and go to properties. Check the linker settings.

Comment: If you see `mfc100.lib` in the linker settings remove it.

Comment: @drescherjm i dont see it anywhere

Comment: Does this project link to any external libraries? Most likely all of the dependencies will need to be updated to use the new compiler.

Comment: @drescherjm yes and they all work the only error i am getting is this one

Comment: If any of those library dependencies were compiled with Visual Studio 2013 or earlier most likely they can not be used and they are likely the cause of the error you see. Visual Studio 2015 through 2022 are binary compatible but not compatible with previous versions of the compiler for any c++ based libraries: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Does the source code contain [`#pragma comment(lib, "mfc100.lib")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp?view=msvc-170) somewhere? Or even more elaborate form, like [in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16725648/1458097), for example?

Comment: @heapunderrun no it doesnt

Comment: @drescherjm so whats the solution? rewrite the project?

Comment: I am not sure I have enough information to give an answer.

Comment: One thing that is worth doing is searching all of the text files in your folder for `mfc100` . Perhaps open notepad++ and search the folder. If any text file contains this text inspect the file. If its a binary file you will need to rebuild it.

Comment: BTW, I did intentionally remove the `.lib` extension from the comment above. It's safer to search without the extension.

Comment: @drescherjm no luck still. I'll try to make another project and copy the old codes into the new project and hopefully that will work

Comment: Hi,ahmad. Is there any update to the question?

Comment: @HuiLiu-MSFT nope i decided I don't care

Comment: Okay. If my answer is helpful to you, you could mark it so that it can help more people.

Comment: @HuiLiu-MSFT sorry brother, but none of the answers worked, I didn't solve the problem, I found the files I needed instead of building them