MFC application migration to visual studio 2022 - LNK1104 cannot open file 'mfc120.lib'
While migrating MFC application to visual studio 2022,getting the following error "LNK1104 cannot open file 'mfc120.lib'"
I believe it is supposed to link to "mfc140.lib" or "mfc14x.lib".
what do I need to change to fix this linker error?

Make sure you are using the V143 toolchain.
Check whether mfc120.lib is added to the project's Linker option, or mfc120.lib is linked in the code. Search for keyword mfc120  in code files and  vcxproj file.
In the VS2022 project settings, set Use of MFC -> use MFC in a static library / shared DLL.
In addition, you may have linked a library that uses mfc120.lib.

Thanks for the response.

There is no explicit reference to mfc120.lib in code or vcxproj files or linker poroject property set.
The use MFC points to MFC as a shared DLL.


Could it be a chained dependency? meaning, a dependent lib is inturn referring to mfc120.lib? if so, how do you identify which library depends on it?



No luck with clean and build.


Here is the linker command line command shown on the Visual Studio project setting
"/OUT: /DYNAMICBASE "winmm.lib" "wmvcore.lib" "shlwapi.lib" "ippcorel.lib" "ippsmerged.lib" "baselib.lib" "setupapi.lib" "dsound.lib" /DELAYLOAD:"dsound.dll"


do you think one of these have the mfc120.lib dependency?


Try /NODEFAULTLIB[:library]. Also check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16725648

ok i have some directions now. >I went to linker properties and set Ignore Specific Default Library to "mfc120.lib;mfcs120.lib". > Then there was a new error, which pointed me to a dependent library named baselib.lib that was referring to "mfc120.lib". > I am trying to build that dependent library from source using latest toolchain.

managed to compile the project after compiling the dependent library with the latest toolchain. thanks!
